# Cannot resolve attribute (of one event function) in MXML

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

I tried many way to solve this error in mxml but failed anyway: 
"Cannot resolve attribute 'colorChanged' for component type com.colorPicker.controls.colorclasses.ColorMap. AdvancedColorChooser.mxml"

```
<ColorPicker:ColorMap id="ColorSelector" modifier="{ColorModifier.value}" mode="{ColorMode}" value="{_value}" colorChanged="
{
   handleColorChange();  <!-- defined in the script region below -->
   return;
}"
/>

...

<mx:Script>
   <![CDATA[

   internal function handleColorChange(arg1:flash.events.Event=null):void
   {
      dispatchEvent(new flash.events.Event("changeEvent"));
      return;
   }

   ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

How should I define the "colorChanged"?

Should I define colorChanged as an event in ColorMap.as? Like this,

```
internal function colorChanged(arg1:flash.events.Event=null):void
{
    return;
}
```

But I got syntax error parsing the mxml file :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line breaks: `colorChanged="handleColorChange()"` should do